# Proving an inequality containing 3 variables

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I am not really sure how to prove this inequality. I thought about using AM-GM for 3 variables ($\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge abc$), but that didn't work out, so I then decided to try and use cases ($x\ge0$) and ($x<0$). However, I couldn't really get that far by doing so.

> Here is the question

Let $a,b,c$ be three real numbers. 
Prove that
$|a-c| \leq |a-b|+|b-c|$

I have tried to simplify this expression by squaring both sides, but that just left me with a mess, and I am not sure what to do next.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Triangle inequality, $|(a-b)+(b-c)|\le|a-b|+|b-c|$

Comment: It may be easier to first prove that $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ (seperate cases: both variables are positive, both are negative, or one is positive and one is negative).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that. I will try to research that theorem and familiarize myself with it before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square of the left-hand side is
$$(a-c)^2 = (a-b+b-c)^2 = (a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + 2 (a-b)(b-c).$$
The square of the right-hand side is
$$(|a-b|+|b-c|)^2 = (a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + 2|a-b||b-c|.$$

So, all you need to do is show $(a-b)(b-c) \le |a-b||b-c|$. Can you finish the job?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am just curious - are we required to show that (a−b)(b−c)≤|a−b||b−c|? Isn't this considered to be an axiom (c≤|c|)?

Comment: @FlavioEsposito Yes this is a simple observation to make, and you probably don't need to explicitly prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Squaring of the both sides helps!

We need to prove that:
$$a^2-2ab+b^2+b^2-2bc+c^2+2|(a-b)(b-c)|\geq a^2-2ac+c^2$$ or
$$|(a-b)(b-c)|\geq(b-a)(b-c),$$ which is obvious.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?